# Congruent cyclic quadrilaterals?

Tags: geometry

Lines $ CF,GE $ are parallel to diagonal $DB$.

[image]

Are the cyclic quadrilaterals $ CBGDC,FBGDF $ (with same sides and angles) congruent?  If not, how are they be described?

Comment: It would be clearer to spell out the four cyclic quadrilaterals you are concerned with.  Clearly $CBGD$ and $FDEB$ are congruent (by reflection), but $CBGD$ and $FBGD$ need not be (assuming distinctness of $C$ and $F$ and of $G$ and $E$, as the illustration indicates).

Comment: Changed to include only two, since the others are anyhow symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Draw the line $l$ through the center $O$ perpendicular to $DB$. Then $l$ passes through the midpoint of $DB$. Moreover $l$ is orthogonal to $CF$ and $GE$ because the two latter chords are parallel to parallel to $DB$. Therefore $l$ passes through the midpoints of $CF$ and $GE$. Consequently a reflection in $l$ maps one quadrilateral into the other.

Comment: Note that this is the symmetry I called attention to in my Comment, and which led to a clarification of the Question that obviates its consideration.  The reflection pointed out does not produce congruence of $CBGDC,FBGDF$ because the "lower" triangles are not swapped.

Comment: I can prove only things that are true. The ones that are not... I do not prove :)... And I did not have time to read your comment...